# What is the difference between GlobalMemoryStatus and GetDiskFreeSpaceEx?

Tags: winapi, compact-framework, windows-ce

I was searching for a function that can give me disk information for a Windows CE 5.0 device. I searched in MSDN and found two different functions for the same task. Please tell me the difference between `GlobalMemoryStatus()` and `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx()`. And also tell when to use `GlobalMemoryStatus()` and when to use `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx()`.

Please don't mention the parameter differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`GlobalMemoryStatus` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885649.aspx) provides information about the computer's [**random access memory**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory) (or, RAM):

> This function gets information on the physical and virtual memory of the system.

The [`GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms890887.aspx) provides information about the computer's [**hard disk drive**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive), or other fixed storage medium:

> This function obtains the following information about the amount of space available on a disk volume: the total amount of space, the total amount of free space, and the amount of free space available to the user associated with the calling thread.

Ask more questions about the difference between those two things on [Super User](http://www.superuser.com/).